# FiiO K3 popping on start & some time after last sound

Tags: usb, audio, pipewire

I have a Fiio K3, which has popping at the start (if nothing played for a bit) and some time after the last sound played.

I had already tried:

- disabling usb suspend for the device (via powertop and manually going to the usb port in `/sys`)
- use both USB 1.0 and 2.0 modes of the device
- searching for updated firmware
- reaching out to FiiO directly (no reply)
- searching for similar issues

Using KDE Plasma Wayland, pipewire and wireplumber.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this issue thanks to [ArchWiki Pipewire#5.1.13](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PipeWire#Noticeable_audio_delay_or_audible_pop/crack_when_starting_playback), which i sadly found after other suggestions which did not work.

Quickly putting what worked for me here from the docs in a simple script:

```bash
# Create the directory if it does not exist already
mkdir -p ~/.config/wireplumber/main.lua.d/

# Write the Config file for the changes
cat << EOF | tee ~/.config/wireplumber/main.lua.d/51-disable-suspension.lua
-- Disable suspend because K3 has popping issues with that

table.insert (alsa_monitor.rules, {
  matches = {
    {
      -- Matches all sources.
      { "node.name", "matches", "alsa_input.*" },
    },
    {
      -- Matches all sinks.
      { "node.name", "matches", "alsa_output.*" },
    },
  },
  apply_properties = {
    ["session.suspend-timeout-seconds"] = 0,  -- 0 disables suspend
  },
})
EOF

# Reload wireplumber to apply the changes
systemctl --user restart wireplumber
```

Note: the script above will disable suspend for all devices
Note: when restarting wireplumber and something like EasyEffects is running, that needs to be killed first, otherwise there will be no sound
Note: other similar posts have noted to copy the *full* file from `/usr/share/wireplumber/main.lua.d/50-alsa-config.lua` and only uncommenting the `session.suspend-timeout-seconds` entry, but that didnt work for me, only the above config worked.